# How to Modify the Start Number for Caption Numbering Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want to start the Figure number with "Figure 102" but every time I insert caption, it starts with "Figure 1"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Word's numbering field "restart" feature to accomplish this...

Based on the MS' KB [WD: How to Modify the Start Number for Caption Numbering](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/145508):

1. Select the number in the caption you want to start the custom numbering at.
2. Right-click and choose "*Edit Field...*".
3. Click the *Options* button.
4. Choose the *Field Specific Switches* tab.
5. Select the `\r` switch, and click *Add To Field*.
6. Type the number desired to restart the caption numbering after the `\r`.
7. Click OK, and then click OK again.

So in the end (depending on you locale and language) the *Field Codes* box should say `SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \r 102`.

Example:

[image: Example Word Page with Custom Figure Numbering]

Comment: when I create a caption with chapter number (heading 1), and do as you described above, every time I insert a caption from the word menu, it resets the start back to 1. How can this be avoided?

Comment: The link above is broken.

Comment: After using this, dont forget to remove \r on next caption to continue numbering